# Skip breaking in blackboxed script when debugging javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging javascript in chrome, I marked a lib (angularjs) file as blackboxed. But when debugging I still enter the angularjs library when stepping over function calls (it shows an empty source file and a message: '
This script is blackboxed in debugger
more
' at the top). Is there a possibility to automatically step over the angularjs lib when it is blackboxed (completely ignore when debugging)?

Comment: This does seem like a bug. Can you reproduce it on this angular app: http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/ ? You can also try using [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) (dev version of Chrome) and see if this was already fixed.

Comment: right click on angular.js --> blackbox script --> resulted in /angular\.js$ pattern in the settings. After manually changing the pattern to angular.js the script was properly blackboxed

Comment: Hm, that's strange `/angular\.js$` is correct, because that's a regex and `.` has a special meaning in regexes and must be escaped. Anyway, I can't reproduce it on http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/ , not sure what you are doing differently. Maybe it was a mater of reloading DevTools?

Comment: It may also have to do with the version of Angular you are using. I recall there being an issue with DevTools being able to successfully blackbox newer versions of Angular, but not older ones. I don't know whick version works, but I can say that I personally am using Angular 1.2 at work, and devtools does not blackbox it.

Comment: doesn't this have to do with they way the debugger works? to me it seems that it only looks at the black boxed list when stepping through code. not for "pause on caught exceptions".